# truffle.js failed to run during setup of Ethereum environment

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, truffle

I'm try to setup my development environment. I've done a clean install of NodeJs, and a clean install of Truffle on Windows 10 Professional . When I try to run a truffle command I get ResourceUnavailable ApplicationFailedException FullyQualifiedErrorId NativeCommandFailed.

here is a screenshot of my logs.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After visiting the Truffle project issues section on gitHub.com. I was directed to try running 'truffle.cmd version' in Powershell which returned the version. I was then able to run truffle.cmd init which unboxed truffle with no issues.